# Javascript HttpRequest POST Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in web server

Tags: javascript, python, json, post, httprequest

I tried to do HttpRequest by JavaScript. Because I had previously received an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, I used Python's SimpleHTTPServer. But still I received the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error message. Is there another way? And is there anything wrong with javascript?

Here is my code.

The server needs :

- basic Authorization
- 'Accept' : 'application/json'
- 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
- 'Content-Length' : '*'
- body written by JSON

And I used the Chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function OnButtonClick() {

  var clientId = "-my ID-";
  var clientSecret = "-my password";

  var authorizationBasic = window.btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('POST', "-my url-");
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
  request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.send(JSON.stringify({email: "-my email-" }));

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
           alert(request.responseText);
        }
      };
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="送信" onclick="OnButtonClick();" />
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Your server needs to send that header.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I know that. I would like to ask if there is no way to add a header to the server. I have tried to use the web server because it has been answered, but it fails and asks again.

Comment: You need to edit your server to send that header.

Comment: Okay. Thank you @SLaks